# Concurrent access to generic list property

Tags: c#, concurrency

I am validating a request object by a list of validators:

```
foreach (var validator in validators)
{
    results.Add(validator.Validate(request));
}
```

Each validator inspects the object and may or may not add an error to the request object's list of error (a List<OrderWarningError>)

```
public override bool? Validate(Request request)
{
    bool isValid = true;

    if (someErrorConditionIsMet)
    {
        isValid = false;
        request.WarningsErrors.Add(new OrderWarningError
        {
            Message = "The request contains an error",
            Severity = EnumWarningErrorSeverity.Error
        });
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

I am now adding more validators and each validator may depend on external data for its business rules so I would like to run each validator concurrently to improve performance.  What is the best way to synchronize access to the generic list property during Add() without changing its data type (is this even possible)?

Can I do this?:

```
lock (request.WarningsErrors)
{
    request.WarningsErrors.Add(new OrderWarningError
    {
        Message = "The request contains an error",
        Severity = EnumWarningErrorSeverity.Error
    });
}
```

Comment: Look into concurrent collection @https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use lock yes but its probably better to use a thread safe collection like those defined in the namespace "System.Collections.Concurrent".

Comment: Along these lines, I generally use ConcurrentBag, and then at the end to a .ToList() to change back into a list.  Keep in mind that you have no idea what order things will end up in (which may or may not be an issue depending on your app).

Comment: using ToList is nice if you want a list but that would generate a non-concurrent list, thus would re-introduce the problem from that point on. You'd be best off just keeping the concurrent bag to ensure the list is always threadsafe.

Comment: That's why I said "at the end".

Comment: "at the end" of what? remember  we are talking about multiple threads here, just because your thread is done with the concurrent stuff it doesn't mean something else is, so you ToList() the bag when the program exits, what's the point to that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that can go wrong with concurrent access to a collection, so let's look at them and see if they apply:

- **Race Conditions:** Symptoms include double entries because another thread inserted an item between the time you checked to see if it exists and the time you added it.  Also you can have issues with editing an item that another thread has already deleted. *In your case, you are only adding 0 or 1 item per validator and order doesn't matter, so this is not really a concern.*
- **Deadlocks:** Basically if you add locks around your collection and you have one thread waiting to add something that another thread is blocking and waiting for it to be added.  There's no resolution so both threads are stuck.  *Since you haven't added locks, this isn't a concern either.  If you do, you have to lock every access to the collection.*
- **ConcurrentModificationExceptions:**  If you are trying to iterate through a collection while another thread is modifying it, then the one iterating will receive the `ConcurrentModificationException`.  NOTE: you can get these if you try to modify a collection while you are iterating through it in the same thread.

In your scenario, you are adding errors, etc. that are unique to each validator.  As long as order is unimportant, you don't need to lock your collection.  You only need to make sure your processing is fully completed before you attempt to iterate through your collection.  *With this special case, you can use any collection to store the results.*

For increased safety, and the ability to iterate while potential modifications are happening, you might want to look at a `ConcurrentBag` or a `ConcurrentQueue`.  (Both in System.Collections.Concurrent).

> Keep in mind processing your validations in parallel might not give you the performance edge you might think you are going to get.

In order for parallel processing to make sense, you have to be dealing with blocking I/O or some other resource intensive task that causes the validations to take a long time.  If your entire validation takes less than 100 ms (0.1s), then parallel processing will only make wall clock time take longer at the price of more complex code.

The easiest construct to make sure all processing is complete before iterating over the error list is the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx) construct.  But I recommend using a [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to test the hypothesis.